# CSS first-child

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is it safe to use CSS pseudo class first-child with regards to browser support and the like?

Thanks.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I find [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/) to be extremely helpful for questions of this sort.

Answer (score 6):

Depends which browser.

IE6 doesn't support it. See [:first-child and :last-child](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/firstchild.html):

> Not supported by Explorer 6- on
>   Windows.
>
> Explorer 7, Safari 3.0, iCab only
>   support :first-child.

Comment: Someone should run a test. PPK is usually very good about noting things like that, and W3Schools isn't always accurate.

Comment: Yep, I just ran a test. IE6 doesn't see :first-child. (Testing on Internet Explorer Collection.) This is how I remember it, too.

Comment: Seriously, one of you should edit that W3schools reference--it's not very clear. What's the current IE? And 'to work in IE' means 'to work in the current IE'--not 6. Perty please.

Comment: w3schools is a relic of history that's best left ignored. If you want to know about current functionality go to quirksmode.

Comment: Agreed, and not to be a pain, but can't you revert your answer so it doesn't include the erroneous info?

Comment: @DN sorry didn't even notice that had been added.

Comment: And no mention of Opera, which does support it: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-firstchild

Answer (score 2):

You can support CSS2 pseudo-classes in IE5/IE6 by using Dean Edwards IE7 JS library

http://dean.edwards.name/IE7/

It's free, easy to use and highly recommended. Just put the following code in your HEAD:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<script src="http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.1(beta2)/IE7.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Despite the BETA label It's never given me any problems and it solves a whole range of IE6 lameness issues.

Comment: +1 for Dean Edwards IE7. I have used that a few times in the past, and, while a little slow, seems to work like a dream.

Answer (score 1):

According to [w3](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pseudo_first-child.asp) it's supported by all major browsers (ie, firefox, opera, chrome, safari) with the caveat that for :first-child to work in ie, a < !DOCTYPE> must be declared.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery would be another option to solve this cross browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can support IE6-8 with selectivizr. It works pretty well.

http://selectivizr.com/